# Can this blown component be identified?

Tags: pcb, power-electronics, ac-motor

I was repurposing a universal motor from a blender for a home project. Unfortunately a screw went through a wire and shorted to ground. Many components are damaged. I'm assuming the motor is fine. The other components I can identify to be replaced. however I have no idea what this one is. Photo attached.

Background information:
240v universal motor
unidentified component is connected with a diode and a capacitor on a pcb
A traic is also part of the circuit ( would this have been damaged too?)
Other than the capacitors on the motor there are no other components to the circuit.

[image]

Edit:Another picture added[image]

Comment: Probably a fuse or a wirewound resistor, but the photo is rather bad. You should take a better one, from closer, and yet another to get an overview of the entire PCB.

Comment: Looks like a fuse with a ceramic tube cover. You can work backwards from the motor's power. Eg, if motor is 200W, then current would be around 1A (P = V * I). You can start with a 240V 5A fuse.

Comment: New photo added @dim

Comment: If you clean the board a bit it may show F1 to indicate a fuse.

Comment: It was a fuse thanks guys

Comment: @tlfang01 if you had posted this as an answer, it could then be accepted by the OP...